# Pod mounts wrong directory on Node when a flexvolume with cifs is configured

Tags: kubernetes, cifs

The following problem occurs on a Kubernetes cluster with 1 master and 3 nodes and also on a single-machine Kubernetes.

I set up the Kubernetes with flexvolume smb support (https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-volume-drivers/tree/master/flexvolume/smb). When I apply a new pod with flexvolume the Node mounts the smb share as expected. But the Pod points his share to some docker directory on the Node.

My installation:

- latest CentOS 7
- latest Kubernetes v1.14.0
  (https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)
- disabled SELinux and disabled firewall
- Docker 1.13.1
- jq and cifs-utils
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/kubernetes-volume-drivers/master/flexvolume/smb/deployment/smb-flexvol-installer/smb installed to /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec/microsoft.com~smb and executable

### Create Pod with

smb-secret.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: smb-secret
type: microsoft.com/smb
data:
  username: YVVzZXI=
  password: YVBhc3N3b3Jk
```

nginx-flex-smb.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-flex-smb
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-flex-smb
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: test
      mountPath: /data
  volumes:
  - name: test
    flexVolume:
      driver: "microsoft.com/smb"
      secretRef:
        name: smb-secret
      options:
        source: "//<host.with.smb.share>/kubetest"
        mountoptions: "vers=3.0,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777"
```

### What happens

- Mount point on Node is created on `/var/lib/kubelet/pods/bef26895-5ac7-11e9-a668-00155db9c92e/volumes/microsoft.com~smb`.
- `mount` returns `//<host.with.smb.share>/kubetest on /var/lib/kubelet/pods/bef26895-5ac7-11e9-a668-00155db9c92e/volumes/microsoft.com~smb/test type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.0,cache=strict,username=aUser,domain=,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=172.27.72.43,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)`
- read and write works as expected on host and on the Node itself
- on Pod

  - `mount`for /data points to `tmpfs on /data type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,size=898680k,nr_inodes=224670,mode=755)`
  - but the content of the directory /data comes from `/run/docker/libcontainerd/8039742ae2a573292cd9f4ef7709bf7583efd0a262b9dc434deaf5e1e20b4002/` on the node.

I tried to install the Pod with a PersistedVolumeClaime and get the same problem. Searching for this problem got me no solutions.

Our other pods uses GlusterFS and heketi which works fine.

Is there maybe a configuration failure? Something missing?

**EDIT: Solution**
I upgraded Docker to the latest validated Version 18.06 and everything works well now.

Comment: Hi @Reto Stadler Could you add your solution as an answer and mark it as approved? It ill make your solution more visible if anyone will be searching for similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded Docker to the latest validated Version 18.06 and everything works well now.

To install it follow the instructions on [Get Docker CE for CentOS](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/).